# How to insert character inside a word while keeping the case

Tags: php, replace

I want to insert a character inside a word in a string if a word match is found while keeping the case. This code works fine but I have to specify the resulting word.

```
$string = "Quick brown fOx jumps right over the lazy dog.";
$swears = array(
    "BROWN" => "BRO.WN",
    "fox"  => "f.ox",
    "Dog"  => "D.og",
);
$filtered = str_ireplace(array_keys($swears), array_values($swears), $string);
```

The problem with this code is any "brown" becomes BRO.WN
Is it possible to insert a character if the word matches. Like Brown becomes Bro.wn; brown becomes bro.wn while keeping the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably much better ways to do that, but here is the only answer I came up with :

```
 foreach($swears as $swear => $modified_swear) {
   $swear_pos = stripos($string, $swear);
   if($swear_pos !== false) {
     $swear_len = strlen($swear);
     if($swear_len >= 3) {
       $new_string = substr($string, 0, $swear_pos);
       $new_string .= substr($string, $swear_pos, $swear_len-2);
       $new_string .= '.';
       $new_string .= substr($string, $swear_pos+($swear_len-2));
       $string = $new_string;
     }
   }
}
```

This code works only if you actually was trying to add a single dot before the two last characters of a swear.

**EDIT :**

New code that can modify all occurences of a list of words.

```
    $searched_pattern = '/\b(?:';
foreach($swears as $swear => $modified_swear) {
  $searched_pattern .= '('.$swear.')|';
}
$searched_pattern = rtrim($searched_pattern, '|');
$searched_pattern .= ')\b/i';

$string = preg_replace_callback(
  $searched_pattern,
  function($matches) {
    $word = $matches[0];
    $swear_len = strlen($word);
    if($swear_len >= 3) {
      $new_word .= substr($word, 0, $swear_len-2);
      $new_word .= '.';
      $new_word .= substr($word, $swear_len-2);
      $word = $new_word;
    }
    return $word;
  },
  $string
);
```

Comment: One more question, this function only checks for the first instance of the keyword, is it possible to check if there are more words in the string like "brown fox with brown cat" should work

Comment: @SaudIqbal This code should overcome your problem (see edit).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly clear what you want?
There are alternatives for this test.  Then do a str_replace inserting a char into a specific position.

```
   <?php
$string = "Quick brown fOx jumps right over the lazy dog.";
$swears = array(
    "BROWN" => "BRO.WN",
    "fox"  => "f.ox",
    "Dog"  => "D.og"
);
$string_arr = explode(" ",$string);
    $swears_arr = array_keys($swears);
    foreach ($swears as $swear_key => $swear_word) {
    foreach ($string_arr as $key => $word) {
        if (preg_replace('/[^a-z]+/i', '', strtolower($word)) == strtolower($swear_key)) {
             $string_arr[$key] = substr_replace($word, '.', 1, 0);
                                 }
                                            } 
                                                   }

    // put the sentence back together:

    $new_string = implode(" ",$string_arr);
print_r($new_string);
    ?>
```